# Svelte Binding Issue - Causing variable to be undefined

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am experiencing an issue with binding values in SvelteKit. It's most likely my understanding of binding rather than a bug.

My +page.svelte loads and its data property is populated with a list of clients successfully. This data is used to populate a select box. When the user selects an option, it triggers an API call that fetches the departments for the selected client and populates another select box.

When the user selects a department it triggers a function to do something else, it doesn't matter. The problem is that the 'departments' variable is somehow set to undefined and the second select box disappears?! If I remove the binding this issue does not occur.

I created a StackBlitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-xsmsj5?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte) to see it in action. Below is my +page.svelte file. I tried swapping around the bind:value and on:change order but that does not help.

Any pointers to what I might be doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<script>
export let data

let clientValue = 0
let departmentValue = 0

$: ({ clients, departments } = data)

async function handleClientSelection(event) {
    const response = await fetch('/api/departments/' + event.target.value)
    departments = await response.json()
}
async function handleDepartmentSelection(event) {
    console.log('handleDepartmentSelection called and did something.')
}
```

```
<label for-='client'>Client: 
<select name="client" bind:value={clientValue} on:change={handleClientSelection}>
    <option value="0" disabled>Select a client</option>
    {#each clients as client}
        <option value={client.id}>{client.title}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
</label>

{#if departments !== undefined && departments !== null}
<label for-='department'>Department: 
<select name="department" bind:value={departmentValue} on:change={handleDepartmentSelection}>
    <option value="" disabled>Select a department</option>
    {#each departments as department}
        <option value={department.id}>{department.title}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
</label>
{/if}
```

Comment: If data only comes with the `clients` property, why do you destructure it to provide departments too?  It seems that your departments list comes from a separate call.  Actually removing the `departments` variable from the destructure statement and declaring it as a regular variable fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi @JoséRamírez thanks for the advice. You are correct, doing it that way works, thank you! One question though, it was my understanding that destructuring like I did would automatically create a reactive variable called departments. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Mistaken.  First, you cannot destructure any arbitrary variable and think that's a good practice.  Second, reactivity in Svelte doesn't work like this.  Svelte makes a variable reactive by means of static code analysis.  You might want to revise the reactivity lessons, and maybe dig a bit more to fully understand.  Cheers.

Comment: Cool, thanks Jose.